# Anagram in C: How do I know if every element of the int array is set to zero?

Tags: c, anagram

This code works partly, it recognizes some anagrams to be anagrams and others not so much. I think the error is occurring in isZero. Would really appreciate some feedback. Here are the directions for each function.

**Algorithm**
Read the first string, then use an array of 26 ints to count how many times each letter has been seen.
Read the second string, this time decrement each letter’s count in the int array. The strings are anagrams if and only if every element in the int array is 0.
Ignore any characters that aren’t letters. Treat upper-case letters as the same as their lower-case equivalent. Help on this is given below.

**main()**
Declares the two char arrays and the int array, then calls the functions described below to solve the problem.

**initialize()**
Clears the contents of all of the char and int arrays before you read the first string. (Set every element in the char arrays to the null character ‘\0‘.)

**getString()**
Prompts for and reads a string from input.
Call the standard library function gets() from as you do this.

**setLetters()**
Loops over every character in the first string, and updates the count for that letter in the int array.
Call the following standard library functions from  as you do this. int isalpha & char tolower
In setLetters() you will need to convert a lower-case character in the range ‘a’...‘z’ to an index in the range 0..25. Use this idea: 
    int index;

```
index = (int) (ch – ‘a’);
```

**checkLetters()**
Loops over every character in the second string, and subtracts 1 from the count for that letter in the int array. Very similar to setLetters().

**isZero()**
Loops over the int array. Returns TRUE if and only if every element is 0,FALSE otherwise.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define MAX 26
#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0

void initialize (char string1[], char string2[], int count[]);
void getString (char string1[], char string2[]);
void setLetters (char string1[], int count[]);
void checkLetters (char string2[], int count[]);
int isZero (int count[]);

void main (void)
{
    char string1[MAX], string2[MAX];
    int count[MAX];

    while (TRUE)
    {
        initialize (string1, string2, count);
        getString (string1, string2);
        setLetters (string1, count);
        checkLetters (string2, count);

        //printf("\n");
        if (isZero(count))
        {
            printf("Anagram ");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Not anagram ");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

void initialize (char string1[], char string2[], int count[])
{
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < MAX; i++)
    {
        string1[i] = '\0';
        string2[i] = '\0';
        count[i] = 0;
    }
}

void getString (char string1[], char string2[])
{
    printf("\n");

    printf("Enter string:  ");
    gets(string1);

    printf("Enter string:  ");
    gets(string2);
}

void setLetters (char string1[], int count[])
{
    int i, 
        index = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < MAX; i++)
    {
        if (isalpha(string1[i]))
        {
            string1[i] = tolower(string1[i]);
            index = (int) (string1[i] - 'a');
            count[index] = (count[index] + 1);
        }
    }
}

void checkLetters (char string2[], count[])
{
    int i, 
        index = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < MAX; i++)
    {
        if (isalpha(string2[i]))
        {
            string2[i] = tolower(string2[i]);
            index = (int) (string2[i] - 'a');
            count[index] = (count[index] - 1);
        }
    }
}

int isZero (int count[])
{
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < MAX; i++)
    {
        if (count[i])
        {
            return TRUE;
        }
        else
        {
            return FALSE;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No.. if a non-zero is found while iterating, immedately return false. If it is not do not return anything.  If the loop drops out having found not non-zeros, return true.

Comment: Shouldn't you be returning FALSE in the of of isZero? You're returning the opposite

Comment: Yeah so with the     if (count[i])  ==> return FALSE = 0.  If not, return TRUE = 1 which will conclude with it not being an anagram. And to confirm, when I use if (count[i]) that is the same as if (count[i] == 0)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your isZero should be as follows.
You're returning `TRUE` if the array has a non-zero value.

```
int isZero (int count[])
{
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < MAX; i++)
    {   
        if (count[i])
        {   
            return FALSE;
        }   
    }   
    return TRUE;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Right now your function `isZero` will `return` `True` as soon as it encounters number > `0` . So you can re-write your function like this-

```
int isZero (int count[])
{
    int i; 
    for(i=0;i<MAX;i++){
        if(count[i])
           return 1 ;  //as soon as number other than 0 is ecnountered function return 1
    } 
    return 0;      // return 0 if all elements are 0 
}
```

Note-  `1 - False` and `0-True` .

Comment: Shouldn't be TRUE is 1 and FALSE = 0?

Comment: @EthanF.  I have just returned the integer values accordingly , not in excat order. You can return `0` as false and `1` as true and make changes accordingly in program .  _Just naming convention used you may use as you like_ .

Comment: When I change it to returning TRUE in the if statement i.e. 1, and return FALSE outside i.e. 0. The code does not work properly. My only hesitation is that in the instructions above for isZero, The directions say that it returns TRUE if every element is 0 and returns FALSE otherwise. But when I put FLASE outside, everything goes to crap. I'm happy its working not, but was wondering why  exactly it needs to be FALSE then TRUE and not TRUE then FALSE.

Answer (score 1):

I checked you isZero, two problems
1. You want to return true is all is zero, not false.
2. You shall return true after check all elements not at the first one.

```
int isZero (int count[])
{
int i;

for (i = 0; i < MAX; i++)
{
    if (count[i])
    {
        return FALSE;
    }
}
return TRUE;
}
```

Comment: Thank you all for your help! Ethan, Padfoot, and Amey, really appreciate it. I don't know I missed that. Code is working now. Btw Padfoot, like the name Sirius Black reference amiright?